# Spring adding Tags build error

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jsp

I have got the following errors and i am unable to find an answer. Can someone help me here.

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.springframework.org/tags"   contact.jsp /Spring3HibernateMaven/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp  line 1  JSP Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"  contact.jsp /Spring3HibernateMaven/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp  line 2  JSP Problem

My JSP code is as follows;

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
```

In my Web.xml the code is as follows;

```
 <jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://www.springframework.org/tags/form</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>spring-form.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

How do i solve this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to configure the taglib in web.xml. Just make sure the org.springframework.web.servlet-xxx.jar is on your classpath (web-inf/lib). It contains the TLD files.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem although I have already spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar on Maven repos.
When I download jar org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar and include in lib. It works.

I don't know why because two jars were totally the same, they just have different names.