# Maven reference for springframework.org/tags form per spring source ide?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Hi new to java and I'm getting the following errors per the following lines from a .jsp that I have inherited.  Using spring source as my editor.

NOTE:  This loads fine per my latest eclipse (kepler) IDE.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

Errors:

Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.springframework.org/tags/
 form"
Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.springframework.org/
 tags"

I have the following defined in my pom.xml:

```
<spring.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why do you have a duplicate spring-web artifact declaration?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring adding Tags build error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244119/spring-adding-tags-build-error)

Comment: Sorry updated....there was a duplicate spring-web in my post!

Comment: However, I'm still getting the error in my eclipse project (.jsp file)

Answer (score 5):

I added:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
   </dependency>
```

To mypom.xml file this will resolved the issue.

Comment: I found I also had to make a change to the JSP file and save it before Eclipse noticed the new taglib file.

Answer (score 4):

Try deleting the **spring-mvc** dependency, updating the maven project without that dependency and then re-add the **spring-mvc** dependency. Probably the .jar file is corrupted (as was the case in my project).

Comment: This was the case in my project too.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> Add the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked seamlessly the answer provided by [user3078016](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3078016/user3078016)..

I simply added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

To my pom.xml and voilá, everything is clean now..

BTW, [version 1.1.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/taglibs/standard) is actually the last (and current) version of this lib since 2005..

Thank you..